# Find differences of ownerships between two home folders?

Tags: shell, files, permissions, file-comparison

I have two home folders: `/home/masi` and `/home/masi_backup` and I would like to find the differences between files of the two directories. 
Pseudocode

```
vimdiff <`ls -la /home/masi` <`ls -la /home/masi_backup`
```

---

How can you compare the differences of ownerships between the two directories?

Comment: `vimdiff <(ls -la /home/masi) <(ls -la /home/masi_backup)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
vimdiff <(find /home/masi -printf "%P %u:%g %m\n" | sort) <(find /home/masi_backup -printf "%P %u:%g %m\n" | sort)
```

(this gives names without the leading `/home/masi` or `/home/masi_backup`, owning user and group, and permissions — the latter weren't mentioned in the question but seem useful, drop `%m` if you don't want them).