# How To Copy Lossless from OSX ext to FAT32 without Ownership/Permissions?

Tags: permissions, filesystems, osx, cp, fat32

I sudo-copied documents from OSX extended filesystem to FAT32. Now, I see that two trees are different by size and by Stephen's command [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/284451/16920)

```
vimdiff <(find /Volumes/fat32/ -printf "%P %u:%g %m\n" | sort) <(find /Users/masi/BitTorrentSync/ -printf "%P %u:%g %m\n" | sort)
```

---

How can you copy lossless from OSX ext to FAT32 without Ownerships/Permissions?

Comment: @Christopher Yes, I actually found out that the files in fat32 take more space than in OSX Extended. It makes sense, since fat32 is older format and less optimized.

Comment: FAT32 doesn't have ownership or permissions, so you can't. What's your objective? Do you want to use FAT32 for transport and then copy thee files back to another OSX machine? Do you want to have the files usable on the FAT32 system but be able to restore the permissions when you copy them to OSX? Something else?

Comment: @Gilles Objective is transport of files between OSX and Linux. Permissions do not matter in the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since permissions do not matter, copying with `cp -R` is fine.

The command you're using to compare the two trees compares the file names, ownership and permission. If you don't care about preserving permissions, don't print out the permissions!

```
vimdiff <(cd /Volumes/fat32/ && find . | sort) <(cd /Users/masi/BitTorrentSync/ && find . | sort)
```

But you should use a file synchronizer: [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) if you always copy in the same direction,
[Unison](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) if to synchronize in both directions.

There is no way to preserve permissions on FAT32. If you wanted to copy files and preserve permissions, you'd need to use a different filesystem or put them in an archive (zip, 7z, tar.gz, …).

Comment: Great proposal about zip, ...! I had not thought about it.

Comment: I really like your `cd ... && find | sort` structure. Just outstanding! So much clearer than `find location ...`.